# Microsoft Bot Framework Tools to create a bot by drag and drop the controls

Tags: botframework

Can someone confirm, does Microsoft release any tool or framework that allows to create a Chat bot by drag and drop the controls instead of writing a code?

I have heard about this kind of tool by someone but not sure, I have searched a lot but not get any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess Microsoft Power Virtual Agent can be used to design the Bot through designer UI.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a 'bot designer' with drag-n-drop controls doesn't exist yet, with no ETA on when such a product will be available. However, the Bot Framework team is investigating what a visual designer might look like.

If this feature is important to you, I would suggest you support the current feature request on the BotBuilder GitHub repo, located [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/5277). Or, create a new feature request if that one doesn't align with your idea.

Hope of help!

Comment: You can still mention "Conversation Learner" project on Labs here: https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-conversation-learner . And there was a project at least one year ago with a bot conversation designer by Microsoft, I remember seeing a few screens but it was only internal and looks like it may have been abandoned

Comment: The standalone version for use with bot framework was abandoned.   They have a product however that does have a conversation flow designer https://dynamics.microsoft.com/en-us/ai/virtual-agent-for-customer-service/